# Twilio ios notify quickstart Error in sending notification with swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, twilio, chat

I am using the twilio quickstart chat app.  After binding which appears it is successful in binding to my phone with a user id because I get this message:

```
Request Body: {"BindingType":"apn","identity":"xxxxxxx","Address":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
Response Body: {"message":"Binding created!"}
Message: Binding created!
JSON: {
    message = "Binding created!";
}
```

but

when I attempt to send a notification I keep getting a strange error.

> NotifySwiftQuickstart[1304:280270] [tcp] tcp_input [C1.1:3] flags=[R] seq=17319241, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=17319241, snd_una=956992709

Not sure what that means and how to fix it so that I get the expected outcome of the notification on the phone that it's bound to.

I am running that latest Xcode version on Big Spur.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the "Request was malformed" The push notifications were rejected by APNs.

Twilio push infrastructure does not support the notifications to not main certificate topic. So application device token and certificate subject must have the same bundle id. For instance, for VoIP notifications the certificate subject must end with ".voip" and the device token app bundle ends with ".voip".

Corrected the push notifications in the app and everything works as intended.